# Why vscode autocomplete don't working in js function?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

When i write code oitside of function everything is fine, but when i create a function, autocomplete inside this function stoped working!
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more info vscode can't know that the parameter within your function must be a `string`.  If you use JSDoc comments to indicate that you'll get the intellisense you expect.

```
/**
 * @param {string} word 
 */
function qweqwe(word) {
  const word = word.   // string intellisense here
}
```

In your second example:

```
const word = "mom";
const werwer = word.
```

vscode can do a good job of predicting the type of `word` from the previous assignment.